# Sharing home network with a router

Tags: home-networking, workgroup

I have an old router and decided to share network with two computers with a work group on windows.
The wifi radio is shut and they communicating through the Ethernet ports on the router.

The question is, how safe is it against intrusions ? both computers have a security suite,but is there a possibility a hacker could get in between the connections of the computers ?

Is it better to disable the work group ?

Comment: Because you disabled the wifi, an intruder needs to hack your router from outside or plug-in his computer into your router via Ethernet cable. Probably, your question is, how safe your old router is against hacking attacks from outside? What type of router do you have?

Comment: Tp-Link TL-WR541G. By outside, do you mean the Internet  ?

Comment: Yes, the Internet. If you are not connected to the Internet, then there is no possibility to come into your network.

Comment: The case here is that both computers receiving Internet access from the modem connected to the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router's firewall is the first and most significant line of defense against the Internet. You're fine. Your main vulnerability will be what you do with those computers (visit sketchy sites, download malware, etc). You're not invulnerable, but you're probably not hiding $10,000+ data, so accept the risk.

To exploit the workgroup feature specifically, the intruder would need direct access to one of your two computers or ethernet cables, or a backdoor onto one of them.

Even then, if the computers are protected with different account names and passwords, things like shared folders (unless you set them public) are shielded from an intruder on the other computer.

-----------------  Below here was my first answer, where I made OP's question more complicated than it really was. -----------------

Based on what [I thought] you said of your connection:  Internet > (possibly a router, 3g internet, or other direct connection) > PC > Router > Other computers.

If so, the only way to invade the "other computers" from the Internet would be to first invade the PC.  With elevated privileges on the PC, one could use it as a platform to begin poking at the other two (by configuring routing on the PC or simply by executing attacks from a remote connection to it).

In this case, even if the two computers are as insecure as Windows 95, their security is equal to the security of your main PC (like building a big stone wall around a rickety shack).

Like the stone wall to rickety shack analogy, though, if that stone wall is breached, the hypothetical Windows 95 boxes are as vulnerable as shacks.

This presumes they do not reach out to the Internet, which would introduce a whole new level of insecurity.

Comment: Thank you,the scheme is like this Modem>Router>Two computers plugged in different Ethernet ports.This connection does share Internet access ,in addition I configured a work group between them.But both computers runs newer versions of windows with reliable security suites, each one.Would it be safe that way ?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  In that case, your router's firewall is the first and most significant line of defense.  You're fine.  Your main vulnerability will be what you do with those computers (visit sketchy sites, download malware, etc).  You're not invulnerable, but you're not hiding $10,000+ data, so accept the risk.